# How to place one box inside another box in 3d

Tags: css, transform

How can I place small box into another box? I coded this for fun in Firefox, but how to achieve same effect in other browsers? Screenshot made in Firefox:

[image: Firefox screenshot]

At the moment it only works correctly(?) in Firefox. Here is a part of the markup:

```
  <div id="cube-inner">
      <div class="side-inner" id="side1"></div>
      <div class="side-inner" id="side2"></div>
      <div class="side-inner" id="side3"></div>
      <div class="side-inner" id="side4"></div>
      <div class="side-inner" id="side5"></div>
      <div class="side-inner" id="side6"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="cube">
      <img class="side" id="side1" src="http://s4.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/previews-middle/525807.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img class="side" id="side2" src="http://s2.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/previews-middle/524603.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img class="side" id="side3" src="http://s2.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/previews-middle/515632.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img class="side" id="side4" src="http://s5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/previews-middle/500278.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img class="side" id="side5" src="http://s5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/previews-middle/503559.jpg" alt=""/>
      <img class="side" id="side6" src="http://s5.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/previews-middle/514249.jpg" alt=""/>
  </div>
```

And the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/293JP/1/) with the full source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use experimental and future features. If you look at the documentation, you will realize that these features are not or just partly supported by the browsers, except Firefox that seems to support them pretty well:

- [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing#Browser_compatibility)
- [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility)
- [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective#Browser_compatibility)
- [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition#Browser_compatibility)

Easiest way to solve the problem is just do nothing and wait until the browser vendors start to support these technologies.

The other way is to use some kind of other technology like JavaScript/JQuery or probably WebGL, which is unfortunately an experimental/future technology too.

Comment: thanks for answer! Probably you right. At the moment I only find out how to place box inside without ability to rotate it: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/293JP/2/)

Comment: @IlyaShubin Both versions of your code worked on FireFox but none of them in Chrome or Opera.

Comment: hmm, this is strange. Second version works in both Opera and Chrome for me, orange box now placed inside ([Opera screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/AuMal3r.png)).